# Is it possible to XSS a query string?

Tags: security, url, xss, code-injection

Given the url:

```
http://www.example.com/abc?q1=foo&q2=<USER SUPPLIED>
```

Is this url attackable?  (Assuming `<USER SUPPLIED>` is not output in the HTML document).

*If* this were printed to an `href` attribute, and was HTML encoded, but not URL or attribute encoded.  What could an attacker do?

Comment: Well its very much dependant on your server-side implementation and how you're gonna use the `q2` parameter. It may be a point of interest though. could you provide a more real-life scenario for your question?

Comment: @KiaPanahi In this case it just defines some parameters for a report, however, there is a chance that an, albeit slightly mangled, version of it could get put back into page in the form of an attribute.

Comment: in that case (of any case that might have any effect in server or client side application, you should make sure (to the best of your knowledge) to sanitize and render moot any/each action that **may** compromise your application's data or behavior integrity. :)

Comment: Yup, no arguments with that.  I just couldn't trace the route back to a browser.  Penny just dropped as to where it is though!  I love those eureka moments.

Comment: @KiaPanahi I've added an 'extra for bonus points'.  I can't think of anything specific that could be bad.  (I'm not saying don't encode properly, just curious for an example).

Answer (score 2):

If the "q2" value is used on the page at all, and it is not sanitazed anyhow (you are doing simple `$_GET['q2']` to read the value), it is considered XSS. Even tho it doesn't get printed anywhere on the page, it creates **Reflected XSS**. Attacker may insert anything instead of the parameter, and if it gets run, or even inserted into your database, he could for example catch your phpmyadmin session cookie, or do other harmless stuff dependant on how your page works with this value.